# Move data to first empty row in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, worksheet

I have the following macro (part of it is copied). I want to move data from the Limas sheet to the Constanta sheet. The Constanta sheet already contains some information. By running the macro, this information disappears.

How do I change the code so that the information from the Limas sheet is copied to the Constanta sheet on the first blank row?

```
Sub Limas()

Dim LSheetMain, LSheet1, LSheet2, LSheet3, LSheet4 As String
Dim LSheet5, LSheet6 As String
Dim LContinue As Boolean
Dim LFirstRow, LRow As Integer
Dim LCurCORow, LCurRRow, LCurRERow, LCurPRow, LCurBRow As Integer

'Set up names of sheets
LSheetMain = "Limas"
LSheet1 = "Constanta"
LSheet2 = "Rastolita"
LSheet3 = "Reghin"
LSheet4 = "Poliesti"
LSheet5 = "Bucharest"
LSheet6 = "Curtiu"

'Initialize variables
LContinue = True
LFirstRow = 2
LRow = LFirstRow
LCurCORow = 2
LCurRRow = 2
LCurRERow = 2
LCurPRow = 2
LCurBRow = 2
LCurCuRow = 2

Sheets(LSheetMain).Select
   'Loop through all column I values until a blank cell is found
While LContinue = True

  'Found a blank cell, do not continue
  If Len(Range("A" & CStr(LRow)).Value) = 0 Then
     LContinue = False

  'Copy and format data
  Else

     '--- "Constanta" ---
     If Range("I" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "Constanta" Then

        'Copy values from columns A, B, C, and H from "Limas" sheet
        Range("A" & CStr(LRow) & ",B" & CStr(LRow) & ",C" & _
          CStr(LRow) & ",H" & CStr(LRow)).Select
        Selection.copy

        'Paste onto "Constanta" sheet
        Sheets(LSheet1).Select
        Range("A" & CStr(LCurCORow)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A1").Select

        'Increment row counter on "Constanta" sheet
        LCurCORow = LCurCORow + 1

        'Go back to "Limas" sheet and continue where left off
        Sheets(LSheetMain).Select

     End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables in this manner means that only the last one on each line is declared as a string; all of the others are declared as variant types.

```
Dim LSheetMain, LSheet1, LSheet2, LSheet3, LSheet4 As String
Dim LSheet5, LSheet6 As String
```

Should be:

```
Dim LSheetMain As String, LSheet1 As String, LSheet2 As String, LSheet3 As String
Dim LSheet4 As String, LSheet5 As String, LSheet6 As String
```

As to your problem moving the data, rather than loop through the rows looking for *Constanta* (or one of the other worksheet names) in column I, filter on column I and copy the visible cells to the appropriate worksheet. Since we only got a portion of your code, I'll assume that you wanted to loop through each of the worksheets, copying from the **Limas** worksheet to the worksheet named the same as your filter.

```
Sub Limas()
    Dim lr As Long, v As Long, vSheets As Variant

    vSheets = Array("Limas", "Constanta", "Rastolita", "Reghin", "Poliesti", "Bucharest", "Curtiu")

    With Sheets(vSheets(0)).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        lr = .Rows.Count
        For v = 1 To UBound(vSheets)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=" & vSheets(v), Operator:=xlAnd
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(9).Offset(1, 0))) Then
                .Range("A2:C" & lr & ",H2:H" & lr).Copy _
                  Destination:=Sheets(vSheets(v)).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ' remove commenting to activate deleting the rows after the copy
                '.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        Next v
    End With

End Sub
```

I've commented out the line that removed the rows from the **Limas** worksheet after copying. After you have tested this, you can uncomment that line. This code snippet assumes that all of those worksheets exist in the workbook.